# HttpGetText Lazarus'а работает не на всех машинах

Tags: windows, delphi, lazarus, synapse

Создал простой проект на Лазарусе, использующий HttpGetText
На двух машинах он возвращает результат с сервера, на третьей HttpGetText возвращает false после результата вызова.

С чем может быть связано?
результат выполнения этой функции на ya.ru - на одной из машин **Невыполнено.**
На других - работает хорошо.

```
function myHttpGet(URL:string):string;
VAR
 myData:TStrings;
 answer:string;
Begin
  answer:='';
  myData:=TStringList.Create;
  if (HttpGetText(URL,myData)) then
   begin
    answer:=myData.Text;
   end
  else
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Невыполнено');
  end;

  myData.destroy;
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(answer);
  myHttpGet:=answer;
end;
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: "Не смогли соединиться с хостом" подозреваю, что проблемная машина ходит в инет через прокси. Браузеры получают его автоматом, а ваша программа - нет